# WMI Query and VB6 error

Tags: vb6, wmi

I'm developing a routine using VB6, you must refresh the screen each second, searching for a specific process running on the system.
I'm using WMI to query processes. But sometimes I get a return "not found", and the application closes. the question is, I can filter the user inside the WMI query using a join or something?

below is my source code

```
Dim UserName As String
Dim UserDomain As String
Dim proc_query As String
Dim proc_results As Object
UserName  = Environ("USERNAME")
proc_query = "select * from Win32_Process where Name = 'Exe1234.EXE'"
Set proc_results = GetObject("Winmgmts:").ExecQuery(proc_query)
For Each info In proc_results
    colProperties = info.GetOwner(strNameOfUser, strUserDomain)  
    If strNameOfUser = UserName Then
        // Call a external .exe
        Unload Me:  Exit For
    End If
Next info
```

Comment: Could you explain better?

Comment: Let me give ou a little tip: 

`On error goto erro

erro:`

Comment: Let me give you another little tip: **Oh my bimba!**

Comment: Oh my bimba! it works